# Give the green background color to the right option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In this code I want when option is selected the right option must get green background color before moving to next question. I added timeout and tried to give the right option green background color. I have tried several methods also searched the solution but none works properly. I added this following piece of code in several functions but this code actually giving the green background only for first question then it retains the green background for right option even after moving to next question.

**JsFiddle Link: [Click Here!](https://jsfiddle.net/0fam6zjy/)**

//Testing Code

```
var answer = this.answer;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var letter = buttons[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].textContent;
    if (letter == answer) {
      buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }     
  }
```

//Testing Code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<title>Random Quiz</title>
<style>
body {
background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.grid {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb;
}

.buttons img
{
width:200px;
}
.grid h1 {
font-family: "Montserrat";
background-color: yellow;
font-size: 35px;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 2px 0px;
border-radius: 50px;
}
hr
{
margin-top: 50px;
    color: yellow;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 2px;
    border: none;
}
#score {
color: yellow;
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;
}

.grid #question {
font-family: "monospace";
font-size: 30px;
color: yellow;
}

.buttons {
margin-top: 30px;
}

#btn0,
#btn1,
#btn2,
#btn3 {

    padding: 0px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
    border: none;
margin: 10px 20px 10px 0px;

}

#btn0:hover,
#btn1:hover,
#btn2:hover,
#btn3:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #ffc107;
}

#btn0:focus,
#btn1:focus,
#btn2:focus,
#btn3:focus {
outline: 0;
}

#progress {
color: #2b2b2b;
font-size: 18px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">
<div id="quiz">
<h1>ABCDE Quiz</h1>
<hr style="margin-bottom: 20px;" />
<p id="question"></p>
<div class="buttons">
<button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
<button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>

<button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
<button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
</div>
<hr style="margin-top: 50px;" />
<footer>
<p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
</footer>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var images = {
"A":"https://i.imgur.com/R00WWzr.png",
"B":"https://i.imgur.com/wJVT1uX.png",
"C":"https://i.imgur.com/4XPvD8R.jpg",
"D":"https://i.imgur.com/vptdvnf.jpg",
"E":"https://i.imgur.com/kqzkJUg.png",
}  
function populate() {
if (quiz.isEnded()) {
showScores();
} else {
// show question
var element = document.getElementById("question");
element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

// show options
var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
element.innerHTML = images[choices[i]]? '<img src="'+images[choices[i]]+'"/>':choices[i];
guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
}

showProgress();
}
};

function guess(id, guess) {
  var button = document.getElementById(id);
  
  button.onclick = function() {
    quiz.guess(guess);
    setTimeout(() => {
      populate();
      //button.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }, 1000);
    //button.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
};

function showProgress() {
var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
var element = document.getElementById("progress");
element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + quiz.questions.length;
};

function showScores() {
var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> You scored: " + quiz.score + "/2</h2>";
var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
};

var questions = [
  
 new Question("Choose A From Below!", ["A", "B", "C", "D"], "A"),

   new Question("Choose B From Below!", ["A", "B", "C", "D"], "B"),
];

function Question(text, choices, answer) {
this.text = text;
this.choices = choices;
this.answer = answer;
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
return this.answer === choice;
}


function Quiz(questions) {
this.score = 0;
this.questions = questions;
this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
if (this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
  
this.score++;
}

this.questionIndex++;
}

Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
}

// create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);

// display quiz
populate();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `jquery` ?

Comment: I find it challenging to achieve your objective with the code as it is. I would try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/g9mthLru/

Comment: @76484 you gave me a solution brother. Thank you! If you want, please write it as an answer so I can mark it as a solution and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code needs to be changed in order to achieve the desired objective. I will share my re-written solution below and try to include comments to explain some of the decisions.

```js
var images = {
  "A": "https://i.imgur.com/R00WWzr.png",
  "B": "https://i.imgur.com/wJVT1uX.png",
  "C": "https://i.imgur.com/4XPvD8R.jpg",
  "D": "https://i.imgur.com/vptdvnf.jpg",
  "E": "https://i.imgur.com/kqzkJUg.png",
}

// I prefer not to use Object-Oriented Programming (classes).
// Instead, I am using simple JS objects to store the data for each quesiton
const questions = [{
    body: "Choose A From Below!",
    choices: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    answer: "A"
  },
  {
    body: "Choose B From Below!",
    choices: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    answer: "B"
  }
];

// Having a single state object makes it easier to understand
// what values are changing throughout the life of the app.
const state = {
  currentQuestionIndex: 0,
  selectedChoiceIndex: null,
  score: 0,
  transitionDelaySeconds: 2
};

// A single render function is easier to comprehend.
// It will render the app according to the current values in the state object.
const render = () => {
  const {
    currentQuestionIndex,
    selectedChoiceIndex,
    score,
    transitionDelaySeconds
  } = state;
  const isComplete = currentQuestionIndex === questions.length;

  if (isComplete) {
    $('#quiz').html(`<h1>Result</h1><h2 id="score">You scored: ${score} / ${questions.length}</h2>`);
  } else {
    const currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
    $('#question').text(currentQuestion.body);

    // Instead of hard-coding our buttons in the HTML,
    // we will generate them dynamically.
    // This would allow us to have varying numbers of choices
    // per question.
    const buttonsHtml = currentQuestion.choices.map((choice, index) => {
      // Use a class to apply the styling for the correct answer,
      // but ONLY IF the user has selected a choice,
      // ie., selectedChoiceIndex !== null
      const isCorrect = selectedChoiceIndex !== null && currentQuestion.answer === choice;
      return `<button class="btn ${isCorrect ? 'correct' : ''}" data-choice-index="${index}">
        <span>
          <img src="${images[choice]}"/>
        </span>
      </button>`
    }).join('');

    $('.buttons').html(buttonsHtml);

    $("#progress").text(`Question ${currentQuestionIndex + 1} of ${questions.length}`);

    if (selectedChoiceIndex !== null) {
      // If selectedChoiceIndex is NOT null,
      // then our user has made a choice.
      // We know we want to render the next question
      // after a duration of time, transitionDelaySeconds
      setTimeout(() => {
        state.currentQuestionIndex += 1;
        state.selectedChoiceIndex = null;
        render();
      }, transitionDelaySeconds * 1000);
    }
  }
};

// Use event delegation to track all choice button clicks.
// We have added a data-attribute to each button so that
// we know to which choice (by index) it refers.
// We update the state accordingly, then re-render.
$('.buttons').on('click', 'button', function() {
  const {
    currentQuestionIndex
  } = state;
  const {
    answer,
    choices
  } = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
  const selectedChoiceIndex = $(this).data('choiceIndex');
  const selectedChoice = choices[selectedChoiceIndex];
  const isCorrect = selectedChoice === answer;

  state.selectedChoiceIndex = selectedChoiceIndex;
  state.score += isCorrect ? 1 : 0;

  render();
});

// Render the initial state of the app.
render();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.grid {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
  box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb;
}

.buttons img {
  width: 200px;
}

.grid h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  background-color: Yellow;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px 0px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: Yellow;
  background-color: Yellow;
  height: 2px;
  border: none;
}

#score {
  color: Yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.grid #question {
  font-family: "monospace";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: Yellow;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffc107;
  outline: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn.correct {
  background: green;
}

.btn span {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#progress {
  color: #2b2b2b;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div id="quiz">
    <h1>ABCDE Quiz</h1>
    <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px;" />
    <p id="question"></p>
    <div class="buttons"></div>
    <hr style="margin-top: 50px;" />
    <footer>
      <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```